# Cannot connect to MySQL due to incorrect time zone

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, timezone

I have made a single java app and I want to try to connect to an sql database when window opened. I have add the my-sql-java-8.0.14.jar connector but when I run the app I get an error message.
I have tried multiple times to re-connect, re-build the database and connect with new one but i still get the below error message.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
 "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect to the dbat testDBPack.MainWindow$1.windowOpened(MainWindow.java:47)
    at java.awt.Window.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.processWindowEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value '????????? ??? GTB' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at testDBPack.MainWindow$1.windowOpened(MainWindow.java:45)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value '????????? ??? GTB' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2241)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2265)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1319)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:966)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
    ... 31 more
"
```

I have checked my credentials, i have sql running but i cannot fix the issue.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    JPanel contentPane;
    static Connection conn;

    public MainWindow() {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Coding Factory");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        setBounds(100, 100, 433, 293);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/teachers";
                String username = "panos123";
                String password = "panagiotis";

                try {
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                }catch (SQLException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect to the db",ex);
                }
            }
        });
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Quality Assistance");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(71, 32, 295, 37);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

        JButton TeachersButton = new JButton(" ");
        TeachersButton.setBounds(10, 144, 46, 34);
        contentPane.add(TeachersButton);
```

Also i have another class for the main:

```
package testDBPack;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class TeachersApp {
    static MainWindow mainFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mainFrame = new MainWindow();
                    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
                    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be key: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value '????????? ??? GTB' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Answer (score 2):

Time zone is not configured. Try using the following url:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/teachers?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: hello the error message for the timezone dissapear but now i still get the i cannot connect to the database plus access denied for user :Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect to the db
 at testDBPack.MainWindow$1.windowOpened(MainWindow.java:47)  and then : Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'panos123'@'%' to database 'db'
 at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)

Comment: Ehh, yeah, "db" should be replaces with db name, try it now

Comment: If this answer helped you, consider marking it as "correct", so that everyone who has the same problem knows.

Comment: hey it helped but did not solve the issue though, the solution was to download the mysql-connector-java-5.1.47 in order to work on my PC,

Comment: But is solved the error in your question ^^ If there were other, unrelated problems - it doesn't matter.